# what is the grammar of the following the journey soon became tedious

Tags: grammar

What is the English Grammar of the following below?

> The journey soon became tedious.

The became is a past tense verb, but the phrase `soon became` confuses me.

Comment: What don't you understand? Do you know the meaning of "soon" and "became"? Do you know that "soon" is an adverb that modifies "became"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The verb "became" is past tense because the speaker is describing a journey that happened in the past.

"Soon" means "soon after the start of the journey", or perhaps "soon after the point on the journey that I described in the previous sentence"

> We left La Paz excited about crossing the Andes, but after we entered the jungle the journey soon became tedious, as the jungle stretched ever on.

Here "soon" = "soon after entering the jungle"

Comment: I suspect that tcvduc thinks that _soon_ can only refer to the future, from now.

Comment: @Colin Fine One hundred percent

Comment: I don't know that *soon* can be used in the past tense, actually.

Comment: @tcvduc: in narrative, pretty well all expressions of time are interpreted relative to the "now" of the story, whether that is past present or even future. But _soon_ is more general tham that: it means "after a short time" and is not tied to any particular time.

Comment: @Colin Fine: I got it, "the word soon is not tied to any particular time", it is great. Am I polite when I use *@Colin Fine One:* with you? I am a 23-year-old kid, I'm from another country, I don't know what shall I write.

Comment: @tcvduc: I'm not sure what you're asking, about politeness. All your replies have had a normal level of internet politeness.

Comment: @Colin Fine: I understand, thank you very much.